# Does the html5 video 'poster' attribute block video load?

Tags: html, performance, video-streaming, html5-video

I am working on a Hero banner for a website that should display a 'poster' image until a video is loaded. The video element is set to 'autoplay'. Both the 'poster' image and video are served from S3.

After some page-load analysis it seems there are occasions where the video loading is waiting for the 'poster' image to load.
For instances where the video has loaded before the 'poster' image, is there a way to simply start the video?

The code is:

```
<video src={'video_url'}
      poster={'poster_url'}
      autoplay
      loop
      muted 
      controlsList='nodownload'>
</video>
```

additionally, the document  is preloading the 'poster' image ( slim templating shown )

```
link rel="preload" as="image" href={'poster_url'}
```

I would like to not use JS for this specific implementation. In general the implementation is quite performant but it seems the data has a high standard deviation - when the page loads fast it loads fast; when it loads slow it loads quite slow.

It is not explicit in the documentation if the 'poster' image will ever block the video loading. However, the [MDN  docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) are quite informative.

Is there a way to guarantee the 'poster' and 'video' will display in the "fastest way" possible?

Edit: clarity

Comment: Did you look in the debugger and see what was happening?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah I have looked in the Chrome dev tools, all I can really tell  is that the 'poster' image is one of the first resources loaded and later on when the video is loaded it has about 100-200ms of "waiting TTFB" time. 
I'm not sure if DNS resolution would be included in the TTFB time ( there are sometimes explicit DNS lookup times but not for this video resource ).

Answer (score 1):

in general, the poster will load before the video.

Chrome will download all images and CSS/ HTML JS before the video - videos are the biggest file in the site (generally...or your JS is really bloated - but that's for another SO post), so they are given the lowest priority.

If your video is set to autoplay & muted - I doubt that anyone would even see the poster: as soon as the video is ready to play, it'll begin playing, and the poster will disappear forever.

Why not try loading the video without the poster altogether?